# Where does the LDS section heading for 1 Corinthians 7 come from?

Tags: lds, marriage, new-testament, 1-corinthians

In [the chapter heading to 1 Corinthians 7 in the official LDS scriptures](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/scriptures/nt/1-cor/7?lang=eng), it states:

> Paul answers special questions about marriage among those called on missions—Paul praises self-discipline.

Where does this come from?  How did the author(s) know that Paul was speaking about those called on missions?  Do they claim revelation as the source, research, or is it just opinion?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The short answer: revelation to Joseph Smith.

The long answer:

The LDS edition of the King James Version (KJV plus references) was authored in 1979 under the direction of the Apostles:

> In 1979 and 1981, following a historic effort led by Elders Thomas S. Monson, Boyd K. Packer, and Bruce R. McConkie of the Quorum of the Twelve Apostles, The Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-day Saints published its own edition of the King James Version of the Bible.
>
> https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/manual/about-the-scriptures/history

This edition includes footnotes with excepts from the [Joseph Smith Translation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_Smith_Translation_of_the_Bible) (selected Biblical translations by Joseph Smith circa 1830).

> But I speak unto you **who are called unto the ministry.** For this I say, brethren, the time that remaineth is but short, that ye shall be sent forth unto the ministry. Even they who have wives, shall be as though they had none; for ye are called and chosen to do the Lord’s work.
>
> [JST, 1 Corinthians 7:29](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/scriptures/jst/jst-1-cor/7.29?lang=eng)

For comparison, the plain KJV:

> But this I say, brethren, the time is short: it remaineth, that both they that have wives be as though they had none;
>
> [KJV, 1 Corinthians 7:29](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/scriptures/nt/1-cor/7.29?lang=eng)

Note the JST was an inspired rather than conventional translation; there's no claim that extant Greek texts have this content.

> The Lord inspired the Prophet Joseph Smith to restore truths to the King James Bible text that had become lost or changed since the original words were written. These restored truths clarified doctrine and improved scriptural understanding.
>
> Because the Lord revealed to Joseph certain truths that the original authors had once recorded...the word translation is used in a broader and different way than usual, for Joseph’s translation was more revelation than literal translation from one language into another.
>
> https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/scriptures/jst/introduction

This interpretation is doctrinally consistent with the otherwise pro-marriage instructions throughout the scriptures. (Genesis 1, Matthew 19, even Paul himself in 1 Timothy 4:3.)

The Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-day Saints follows Paul's instruction, in that the vast majority of its full-time missionaries are required to be single. As Paul said, those responsibilities are incompatible with marriage. (But following that full-time service they would marry and raise children.)

Comment: Very nice, thank you.  That's some excellent sleuthing work ;-)

Answer (score 3):

The first chapter headings come from 1979 when Elders Thomas S. Monson, Boyd K. Packer, and Bruce R. McConkie of the Quorum of the Twelve Apostles helped put together the first LDS version of the King James Bible.<sup>1</sup>

2004-2013

> Under the direction of the First Presidency and Quorum of the Twelve, the Church’s Scriptures Committee began working on a new edition of the scriptures....Study aids were also updated: errors and dated information in cross-references were removed, and contextual adjustments in the section headings of the Doctrine and Covenants were made.<sup>1</sup>

<sub>1 [History of LDS Scriptures](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/scriptures/history?lang=eng#gallery=1979-20)</sub>

<sub>see also [Church Publishes First LDS Edition of the Bible](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/ensign/1979/10/church-publishes-first-lds-edition-of-the-bible?lang=eng)</sub>

Comment: Thanks.  Do/did the Elders have a source for that information, did they claim revelation for those chapter headings, or is/was it just their opinion?

Comment: @Freedom_Ben I would recommend reading the see also article, it contains more details and as much information on this question that I could find

Comment: I read the article but didn't really find the answer.  It sounds like in general the headings came from various sources compiled by Bruce R McConkie, including cross-references and JST, etc. But where the one for 1 Corinthians 7 come from?

Comment: @Freedom_Ben I don't think you will find specifics about who made which specific heading. It would be safe to assume (IMO) that Bruce R McConkie compiled it